# react native animated text inside carousel

Tags: react-native, carousel

How to animate a text inside a RN Carousel, like TextTicker from 'react-native-text-ticker' or MarqueeText from 'react-native-marquee' ?
I tried to include a TextTicker inside a Carousel it didn't work ?...

```
render() {
    return (
    <View>
            <Carousel
                ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
                renderItem={this._renderCarouselItem.bind(this)}
                sliderWidth={'100'}
                itemWidth={'100'}
            />
    </View>
    );
}

_renderCarouselItem ({item, index}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextTicker
               style={{ fontSize: 24 }}
               duration={3000}
               loop
               bounce
               repeatSpacer={50}
               marqueeDelay={1000}
            >
          Super long piece of text is long. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            </TextTicker>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: Try providing data prop to the Carousel because renderItem takes items from data and renders it to the list

Comment: added data={carouselFlatListData}, it works